# Is there a way to use Line-In and Mic-In at the same time

Tags: microphone

I was wondering if it is possible to use the microphone and line in at once. Is there a program that emulates a new audio device which is using two or more devices?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: See what your sound mixer app can do.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that all depends, a lot of that depends on what kind of soundcard you have. If you're using onboard audio, I would guess you're stuck with a device that has only one DAC input mixer channel. I'd recommend buying a high end soundcard that has separate inputs. I could be wrong though, keep asking around.